# How to do prev next page?

Tags: c#, wpf

wpf how to do prev next page.
Control can be used?
Like this

```
prev 1 2 3 4 5 ... 20 next
```

I found this but I don't know how to use it.

```
var dicts = (from m in db.sys_Dictionary
             orderby m.sd_Key 
             select m).Skip(90).Take(10);
```

I can run the linq to but I don't know how to make it a complete portfolio.

I find a lot of data are b / s, I need the paging function of the c / s, thanks.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean by b/s and c/s.

Comment: bs is web application.cs is Desktop application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you just posted is a linq query, but can't really be explained if you don't know how linq works,. basically that statements says **select** all from table m aka **database context** db table name sys_Dictionary and **order by** column sd_Key.
Then whats thats evaulated it uses the Skip method to skip the first 90 returned and only return the next 10 records.

The problem that you don't understand is that this will only page this instance. To set up a next prev page thing you should set up a paging class like so

```
public PaginatedList<T>(IQueryable<T> source, int pageIndex, int? pageSize)
{
    PageIndex = pageIndex; //global variable
    PageSize = pageSize ?? source.Count(); //global variable
    TotalCount = source.Count(); //global variable
    TotalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling(TotalCount /(double)PageSize); //global variable
    this.AddRange(source.Skip(PageIndex*PageSize).Take(PageSize));
}
```

then you have two methods, one that has a **HasPreviousPage** and one that has a **HasNextPage**

example

```
  public bool HasPreviousPage
  {  
      get
      {
          return(PageIndex >0); //same global variable
      }
   }
```

then from their you can pass in your info and return that page for example

```
int page= 6;
var dictspage = new PaginatedList<m>(dicts, page, 10); //remove the skip and take from your dicts
```